# How to parse /Date(-62135596800000)/ to null

Tags: angularjs, date, momentjs

I get from the server dates, sometimes `null`, and my filter parse `/Date(-62135596800000)/` to `0001-01-01` but I would like to have empty string.

How can I do this?
Here's my filter:

```
filter('myDateFormat', function() {
    return function (data) {
        return moment(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    };
})
```

Comment: When do you want an empty string?

Comment: If date is /Date(-62135596800000)/? I know I can use if, but I'm looking for  a better sollution

Comment: Just for that single input? I see no better solution then using a simple `if` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your server is returning you null or a date string.
null can be handled by simple null check but for your other input `"Date(-62135596800000)"` which is a valid date, you can't return empty string, without explicitly checking for it.

```
moment(Date(-62135596800000)).isValid() // return 'true'
```

you may try below code.

```
// if inputDate not defined or null    
if (!inputDate || inputDate == null) {
       return '';
} else if (moment(inputDate).isValid()){
       return moment(inputDate).format("DD MM YYYY");
} else {
       return '';
}
```

but if your server is returning this specific date occasionally 'Date(-62135596800000)' and you want to avoid this, you can put explicit check for it.

```
if (!inputDate || inputDate == null) {
   return '';
} 

if (inputDate == 'Date(-62135596800000)') {
     return '';
} else if (moment(inputDate).isValid()) {
     return moment(inputDate).format("DD MM YYYY");
} else {
     return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter could be improved like this:

```
filter('myDateFormat', function() {
    return function (data) {
        return data > 0 ? moment(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD") : "";
    };
})
```

Comment: Code-only and "try this" answers are generally discouraged; try to explain what the change is and why it should work.

Comment: I thought you want to parse null data to empty string. If you want to parse out the negative values as empty strings also, you should check for data to be positive.
I have updated my answer with the data positive check.

Answer (score 0):

First of all decide what should be your **minimum** date.
For example SQL's minimum date is `1753-01-01`
After that compare your date with this **minimum** date like:

```
filter('myDateFormat', function() {
    return function (data) {
        var minDate = moment('1753-01-01');// decide your minimum date
        return moment(data).diff(minDate) > 0 ? moment(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD") : "";
    };
})
```